# Responsive JavaScript – load/hide specific function related to browser width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, responsive-design, bxslider

first fo all: i'm not into JavaScript/JQuery! …but i will try to point out what i want to do.

i'm using the fantastic bx-slider on my page and i made my website responsive via media queries which both works great so far. …but there are some features from the bx-slider-script which i don't want to get active on a specific browser-width. here's what i want:

browser-width LOWER than 500px = load this function:

```
$('#slider4').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 2,
    slideWidth: 230,
    slideMargin: 10,
    nextSelector: '#next',
    prevSelector: '#prev',
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    pager: false,
    useCSS: false,
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    speed: 1000
});
```

browser-width HIGHER than 500px = hide the function above and load this one:

```
$('#slider4').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 4,
    maxSlides: 4,
    slideWidth: 230,
    slideMargin: 20,
    nextSelector: '#next',
    prevSelector: '#prev',
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    pager: false,
    useCSS: false,
    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
    speed: 1000
});
```

…is that even possible in JavaScript? I tried some scripts which are using breaking points but it think my JS-knowledge is to weak to get this to work as i want.

It would be great if there's someone out here which can show me how to do this easily!

Comment: @Spontifixus: ..why did you remove the "thanks"?

Comment: There is a consesus of the community here on Stack Overflow to remove salutations and signatures from posts. See [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/195761) on meta for further details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If($(document).width() < 500){
...
}else{
...
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/width/

You may also want to put in an onchange event

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
 resizefunction();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not working.. i tried to replace the "…" with the functions above but now the script gets no longer loaded!?!

Comment: I'm sorry man.. i think i missed something in the first place.. it wokrs now! thanks! and btw: is there a way to reload the page automatically when reched the given width?

Comment: Sure you can, one of the easiest ways is to add document.location='thispage'; to the resize function inside an if(){} see this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jDkDJ/5/

Comment: @JochenSchmidt I made a stupid mistake (which would cause an endless reload) so i updated the link in the above post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39406/discussion-between-iesus-sonesson-and-jochen-schmidt)