# remove javascript fies at certain browser resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working at a parallax horizontal scrolling website, but  i want to have a different (more "classic") mobile version. The problem is that some .js files don t let me have a normal vertical scroll.

My question is how can i remove these files when the browser width is less than x px?

Comment: Can't you just not initialize the javascript files on mobile devices?

Comment: Try searching for previous questions before you ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422264/responsive-javascript-load-hide-specific-function-related-to-browser-width

Comment: zgood thank you, but i would like to remove these files on desktop as well when users resize browser window.
 Juan E i m trying to remove multiple JavaScript FILES not just some functions.

Comment: Basically JS media queries - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: @TroyThompson : Thank you for your answer... because of my poor js skills i don t really know where i can add my files in this syntax. for example:
 if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}

Comment: Do you have a demo of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Change the js-functions that trouble you so they check the size of the browser window first.
jQuery:

```
$(window).width(); //and-or .height()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the width of the window, and add the script reference.

```
    if(window.innerWidth < 1000)
    {                                                                             
          var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head'); 
          var mobileScript = document.createElement('script');

          mobileScript.src = "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js";
          mobileScript.type= "text/javascript";
          mobileScript.languaje= "Javascript";

          head[0].appendChild(mobileScript);              
     }
```